# Using ANTLR3 C++ code generation

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr3

I want to use ANTLR 3.5 in a C++ program of mine, but I'm running into trouble with how to actually make use of the parser and lexer that gets generated. Using a grammar similar to the one [here](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Five+minute+introduction+to+ANTLR+3), I can do something like SimpleCalcParser.expr(). However, if I want to do something more complex (e.g. parse a language that doesn't just result in a single value, but something more imperative or declarative), it seems quite difficult with the C++ target. As far as I can tell, there is no ability to output an AST or template. Without this, I'm not sure how you can do anything other than just determine if your input parsed correctly or not. Does anyone know how to do this with the C++ target, or would using the C target to generate an AST and using that in C++ be a better option?

Answer (score 0):

some time ago I created some patches for C++ target(see github). There should be AST generation added(but not 100% complete) and also added some tests, which you can use as an example. With current ATLR 3.5 each rule has to return some complex class as a value. And you have to "build" tree manually by using rule actions.

Comment: It looks like using "output=AST" in options still isn't supported when I try to compile with it on. Is there still a tree node that gets passed through as parsing is done? Is there any special syntax for returning a complex class as a value? The tests which involve tree creation aren't actually run, so I'm not sure how they'll help.

Comment: try to compile your own tool from this branch https://github.com/ibre5041/antlr3/tree/e33569be400290689c71923869c317aeadf6168c . Also here are some tests https://github.com/ibre5041/antlr3/tree/e33569be400290689c71923869c317aeadf6168c/runtime/Cpp/tests. Also look at example s003.g